# Powershell jump to another script

Tags: windows, powershell

One of the lesser known features of DOS and DOS-like command files is that a line that starts with the name (path) of a batch file transfers control to the new file, with no return (as opposed to the "call" command which returns when execution is complete).

Can I do this with Powershell too? It's a bit like "goto otherscript.ps1" but I know there is no goto in Powershell.

The reason for asking is that I want to update the currently executing script from subversion if changes are available, and then execute the updated file from the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dot sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) to run an external script - e.g.:

**main.ps1**

```bsh
. ".\sub.ps1"
```

**sub.ps1**

```bsh
write-host "aaa"
```

It's more like an "include" than a goto as it runs in the current script's context and can access / modify variables in the main script:

**main.ps1**

```bsh
. ".\sub.ps1"
write-host $x
# ^ outputs "bbb"
```

**sub.ps1**

```bsh
$x = "bbb"
write-host "aaa"
```

You can prevent the dot sourced script accessing the main script's context if you use the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#call-operator-) - e.g.

**main.ps1**

```bsh
& { . ".\sub.ps1" }
write-host $x
# ^ outputs a blank line
```

**sub.ps1**

```bsh
$x = "bbb"
write-host "aaa"
```

If you put an `exit` after the dot sourced script it'll end the main script and kinda-sorta be like a goto...